# hibernate gets refused connection for non default mysql port

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am connecting to a MySQL(5.1.6) database from Linux on default 3306 port and everything is fine:

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wpdb" />
<property name="username" value="root" />
<property name="password" value="" />
```

Now, I go in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and change default port to 3307 (both [client] and [mysqld]) restart MySQL, adapt hibernate connection url:

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/wpdb" />
<property name="username" value="root" />
<property name="password" value="" />
```

and restart jboss. this time I am no longer able to connect:

```
08:22:05,276 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (MSC service thread 1-13) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
08:22:05,276 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (MSC service thread 1-13) Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
08:22:05,277 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (MSC service thread 1-13) Could not obtain connection to query metadata: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2209) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173) [spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164) [spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149) [spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119) [spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81) [spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:114) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2163) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2159) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1383) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954) [hibernate-annotations-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860) [spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779) [spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211) [spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:400) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) [spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79) [spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70) [spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:103) [spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:343) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2132) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:]
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Any idea what could be the reason mysql refuses connection? No other configuration were changed..but MySQL default port. There are no firewall up and running either.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Did you have another configuration file like connection properties. If you have you have to update them too.

Comment: The last line indicates a MySQL side configuration issue. Can you connect to the port at all: `telnet localhost 3307`? Can you log in to MySQL with a user?

Comment: there is no connection properties file either...the datasource is only defined in spring's application context file.

Comment: telnet connects and mysql too. only teh hibernate seems to get refused for some unknown reason.

Comment: i also tried to connect from a php page:  

<code>
    <?php
    $link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3307', 'root', '');
    if (!$link) 
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
</code>  

and it worked just fine. Still not ubale to connect from jboss/hibernate

Comment: I tried also a simple java project in order to test jdbc conenctivity and stil lsame error message Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused. Tried connecting with non root user too, but no help: String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/wpdb";
  String username = "joe";
  String password = "joe";
  Connection conn = null;
  try
  {
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
  }

Comment: I found the problem/solution. The problem was due to mysql-connect-java-5.1.9. Replaced it with mysql-connector-java-5.1.12 and thing work fine on non standar mysql port too.  This seems to be a known bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=51603 .

Comment: Nice! Are you able to post and accept your own answer?

Answer (score 1):

first you can check what options are being used in the server you can run:

```
   mysqld --verbose --help
```

Stops the service doing

```
  sudo service mysql stop
```

The option that should be changed is port in [mysqld] section, as you said before this is on the /etc/mysql/my.cnf but be sure that the file "~/.my.cnf" (if exists) is not overriding the port. Anyway the idea is to set port as depicted below:

```
   port            = 3307
```

And finally start the MySQL service again, and of course JBoss.

```
   sudo service mysql start
```

Check the port with mysqld --verbose --help, and see if all is as you expected.

In the other hand, you can test the connection using some client application and the same  connector jar. I.e: SQuirrel, and coping the library in the corresponding lib directory. This really helps me when I had issues like that.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem like this.Better to change the jdbc mysql driver of another version.because when i am using mysql 5.1.9 driver it raises connection refused (The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.) problem then I switched another version like 5.1.18 it works.